# Linq DELETE generates UPDATE query in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have database model:[image]

CONSTRAINT [FK_applications_orders] FOREIGN KEY ([order_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[orders] ([order_id])

And controller action:

```
using (var tx = Database.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var order = Database.Set<Order>().Find(someID);

    var apps = Database.Set<Applications>().Where(x => x.Order.Id == order.Id).ToList();
    Database.Delete(order);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

I open SQL profiler to inspect what this line `var apps = Database...` generates, and look at this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Applications]
SET [order_id] = NULL
WHERE (([application_id] = @0) AND ([order_id] = @1))
',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 int',@0=SomeId,@1=SomeOtherId
```

**So why does the Delete call generate an UPDATE query in SQL server?**

Comment: If you comment out `Database.Delete(order);` does it still occur?

Comment: I think your delete of an order is causing the application table to be updated to enforce your constraint.

Comment: @mjwills it doesn't if I comment out `Database.Delete(order)`

Comment: Of course it does not ... because the statement is caused by Database.Delete

Comment: Comment out only the Where and you will still see the update statement

Comment: I would suggest you to either delete or update your question because apparently the `UPDATE` query is not caused by *Linq where clause*

Answer (score 3):

You have a FK constraint between Orders and Applications.

When you delete from the Orders table, EF will be doing an update on the Applicatoins table to enforce this constraint.

e.g. you have the following tables

**Orders**

```
order_id
1
2
```

**Applications**

```
application_id | order_id
     100       |    1
     101       |    2
```

When you delete an order (say `order_id 1`) if EF didn't do an update you would end up with

**Orders**

```
order_id
2
```

**Applications**

```
application_id | order_id
     100       |    1  <---- What is this now ???
     101       |    2
```

So it is updating that field to set it to null.

**Applications**

```
application_id | order_id
     100       |    null
     101       |    2
```